# Keeping two correlated variables in the model

Tags: least-squares, multicollinearity

I am using OLS:

In my model I have two variable (X1 & X2) which are correlated (correlation = 0.47).

My prediction is that X1 should be negatively associated with Y and X2 should be positively associated with Y (Y is the dependent).

When I test the model with control variables and just X1 the coefficient for X1 is positive.(**against** my predictions)
When I test the model with control variables and just X2 the coefficient for X2 is positive.(in line with my prediction)

When I test the model with control variables and both X1 and X2 in the model the coefficient for X1 becomes negative and the coefficient for X2 stays positive (the adjusted r-squared improves).

Can I keep these two variables in the model? Theoretically I can justify that, but is it statistically correct to do so? Is there a reference paper for such conditions?

P.s: I am using observed data with 48000 observations.

Comment: A pairwise correlation of .47 is not a level of collinearity most people would care about. The typical rule of thumb is that collinearity is problematic when the VIF > 10.  That implies a pairwise r >.95.  Your VIF is presumably ~1.3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem you have has to do with multicollinearity (which you included as a tag). The answer is somewhat open-ended as it depends on the data you are using and what you intend to do with it. If you are using your OLS just as a predictor, then leaving in the multicollinearity is fine. It would pose a problem, however, if you are trying to explain a relationship in a research setting. Contextually, it does not seem like you are using binary variables, but if you are, there is a potential for multi-colinearity if you fall into the dummy variable trap as well. For more information, I would suggest referencing the "remedies" section on the Wikipedia page for multicollinearity. https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multicollinearity#/Remedies_for_multicollinearity

Comment: Both variables are continuous. One is geographic distance and the other is cultural differences and it makes sense for them to correlate. I am using it for a research and it is surprising that the geographic distance has a positive association with trade! Interestingly when I add cultural distance then the sign of geographic distance changes to negative.

Comment: Note that correlation of 0.47 a far from multicollinearity, as @gung notes in the comment to the OP.

Comment: Even severe multicollinearity with this simple model in the presence of its 48000 observations might not be a problem.  This is a case of the OP not really telling us enough to give a good answer.

Comment: As I searched more, it could be a case of suppression effect probably...